# Управлять браузерной программой через другое приложение

Tags: delphi

Существует конечная браузерная форма (условно назовем ее "Специфика товара") включающая много типовых форм для заполнения. Имеется три типа форм: например с текстом "название", куда вводится текст; выбором из нескольких позиций (например "Розница", "Опт") и установкой даты приема и планируемой продажи. И эту форму необходимо открывать  и заполнять каждый раз, в случае идентичности товара, для каждого окна более высокого порядка (например товар -"Рис" поступил в бокс1, бокс 2 и т.д.) и для каждого бокса нужно писать одно и тоже. Идея в том, что заполняется файл например в Экселе и оттуда программкой автоматически копируется в конечную форму.
Пишу на делфи, но дальше

```
begin
Hnd:=FindWindow(nil, 'ttt - Opera');
if Hnd <>0 then begin showmessage('nasshel)');
windows.SetForegroundWindow(Hnd);//  активизируем окно
```

не продвинулся. не хочет искать через

```
hh := FindWindowEx( Hnd, 0, 'Товар', ''); //Ищем в дочках класс 
if hh<>0 then showmessage('+')
```

Может поможет кто? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Набросал утилитку просмотра дочерних элементов, проверил на браузерах. Firefox и Chrome (у меня нет оперы на компьютере) более не отдают дочерние элементы своих окон, скорее всего, в целях безопасности. Я бы смотрел в сторону создания своих окон через TWebBrowser, к примеру.

Comment: странный метод решения имхо. либо юзайте встроенный браузер, либо пишите какое-нибудь расширение для браузера.